# Doppler effect and constant velocity of a wave

Tags: special-relativity, photons, doppler-effect

Why doesn't the velocity of a photon change when it is emitted from a source moving with certain velocity? If a photon is a particle then it should have a lower velocity than one which is emitted from stationary source. But it is not true. How does a photon always gain constant velocity in spite of the source's motion? Is it accelerated according to the source's velocity inside an atom before being emitted?  Or are there any other reasons behind this?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94049/109928

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137613/109928

Answer (score 0):

Light sometimes *behaves* like a wave, sometimes like a particle, but for most people the idea of a photon being a particle is misleading because we tend to think of a particle as having mass and taking up space.  Because a photon has no mass it is *required* to travel at light-speed (which is actually the speed of causality).  It does not gain velocity - from the very instant it is emitted it is going at the fastest possible speed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question and objections make complete sense in a Galilean world, a world of 3 orthonormal space dimensions where time is independent and universal: that is, all observers agree on the same clock (and ruler). In such a place, all velocities are additive. (Note: our slow moving daily lives are approximately Galilean--and Galilean transformations can be used to transform reference frames).

In reality, we live (locally) in Minkowski space, where the space dimensions mix with the time dimension, and different moving observers have different clocks and rulers. One needs Lorentz transformations to connect reference frames.

If find the number one stumbling block to understanding the latter is the lack of simultaneity. Moving observers cannot always agree on time ordering, and forgetting this leads to many paradoxes (apparent, of course).

Answer (score -1):

In particle physics, photon is one of the fundamental ingredients of the Standard Model (SM) which explains all the particles/fields and their interactions. A symmetry group particularly $SU(3)_C\times SU(2)_L\times U(1)_Y$ governs all the properties and interactions of those particles. In very small distances ($\lt 10^{-18}$m) or at very high energies those particles are all required to be massless by the theory, at low energies however some of those particles acquire masses by a mechanism called symmetry breaking and photon associated with electromagnetic interactions stays massless. In Relativity, massless particles are destined to travel at the speed of light which is the ultimate limit for matter particles. That's why, for example, the range of the electromagnetic interactions is infinite. The answer of your question thus lies in 4-dimensional relativistic structure. As JEB already mentioned above that Lorentz transformations of 4D spacetime is quite different than Galilean transformations of 3D space.

Comment: Thanks for all to answer this question. I also have contradictions in the idea space time. It is incredible to me. S

Comment: We know that the vacuum is a physical medium characterized by an electric permitivity and a magnetic permeability with Ɛ.μ=c², if we suppose that the speed of light (photons) exceeds or is inferior to the celerity of light c for an observer, it is that the physical characteristics are variable as Ɛ  and μ, which is difficult to ''swallow''.